# In which reactjs lifecycle method we should not write the code to update state?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the react JS lifecycle methods and came across a question that in which of the following methods we are not suppose to call `setState()` functionality to update the component:

- `componentWillMount()`
- `componentDidMount()`
- `shouldComponentUpdate()`
- `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: update not up[date

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount()`
Basically, this will be invoked before render(), thus, it will never trigger a re-render, so you need to avoid using `setState()` in it.

Further, `componentDidMount()` is originally the WHERE you are going to make AJAX requests, else, it's totally ok to use the setState in the life cycle methods you asked for.

Ref to read: [React Lifecycle Methods- how and when to use them](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1)

Comment: perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general: try to keep `setState` usage for user interactions like event handlers.

`componentWillMount`: this was good point where to call `setState`, but this method is deprecated so try to stop using it. Use the class constructor instead.

`componentDidUpdate`: you *can* call `setState` here but it will trigger a new render (and so another call to `componentDidUpdate` itself). If you really want, you will commonly call `setState` here behind some sort of condition.

`componentDidMount`: same as above, you will trigger a new render immediately after the mount so this is not encouraged for performance reason.
A good exception: fetch/AJAX actions perform here.

`shouldComponentUpdate`: no, keep this method only for evaluating if you must perform a re-render or not. In general: do not use side-effects like `setState` here.

Keep in mind you have available the `getDerivedStateFromProps` static method if you need to eval a state based on props (this commonly cover any usage of `setState` inside didMount/didUpdate).

Most of the time a new `key` prop on a component will remove the needs of other complex `setState` usage around your code.

See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Comment: Just one point here, as you said that componentDidUpdate() is a good place to call setState() but it will trigger a new render and a call to  componentDidUpdate() itself then won't it go into a loop?

Comment: @KeshavJha exactly, so I said "behind a condition".